# Равномерно распределенные элементы массивов

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Пример. Имеется `numpy` массив состоящий из `1, 2, 3`. Как поделить его на `5` массивов, чтобы частота вхождения `1, 2, 3` в каждый из них была равна или очень близка к частоте появления этих чисел в изначальном массиве?

Т.е. дано `a` - массив, `k` - число новых массивов. Нужно вывести `k` массивов примерно одинаковой длины (отличаются не более чем на 1), которые являются непересекающимися частями исходного массива и которые удовлетворят "частотному" условию.

Как это реализовать?

Моя идея - словарь. Ключ - элемент массива. Значение - число вхождений. А дальше собрать эти `k` массивов.

А можно ли методами векторизации? Здесь ведь дискретное равномерное распределение. По идее должно быть более лаконичное решение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120297/discussion-on-question-by-shorty12319----).